# Hplip with problem, CUPs dont delete duplicate printer and error to communication

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 and I have an **HP printer Deskjet 5822**. I usually install by the drivers from the manufacturer itself, as they are updated in relation to the official cannonical repository.

After installing the package, I started to notice a flaw, being informed by the system of a communication problem with the printer. The principle suspected that it could be the cable, because I always connect it via USB. But in tests on a Windows machine, the printer works normally, only having problems on ubuntu.

In forum searches, I noticed that several people had problems with the **CUPS** module and **HPLIP**. Initially to install I got similar problems, since **hplip-gui** did not find the printer's ppd file. Such a problem being motivated by the CUPS process being turned off. After activating **CUPS**, the current problem is being in the communication, because it generates two printer inputs, thus not allowing the printer to be used, since it cannot communicate properly.

To help with the analysis, an error report is generated, generated by `hp-check`:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.5)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.     
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball has the proper dependencies installed to successfully   
run.                                                                                                                                                                                                               
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).                                                         

Check types:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                                                                                                                                                             
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)                                                                                                                                       
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                                                                                                                                                          
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                                                                                                                                                       
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                                                                                                                                                   

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

|Gtk-Message: 00:29:36.711: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Host: Predator-G3-572
 Proc: 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.20.5
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.20.5

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.20.5
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.20.5
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.20.5
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[fax]
email_address = 
voice_phone = 

[installation]
date_time = 06/07/20 00:29:37
version = 3.20.5

[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=BR816FF15F06BN"
printer_name = 
working_dir = .

[polling]
device_list = 
enable = false
interval = 5

[refresh]
enable = false
rate = 30
type = 1

[settings]
systray_messages = 0
systray_visible = 0

[upgrade]
last_upgraded_time = 1591495438
latest_available_version = 3.17.10
notify_upgrade = true
pending_upgrade_time = 0


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.3.1           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
Gtk-Message: 00:29:38.505: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 00:29:38.527: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.3.1           OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.8             OK         -
 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           OK         -
 python3-notify2      Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 python3-pyqt5-dbus   PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5                         OPTIONAL        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-pyqt5        PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        5.0             5.14.1          OK         -
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               7.0.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.34          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.20.5          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.20.5          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.20.5          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.20.5          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=BR816FF15F06BN' is a Hewlett-Packard DeskJet_5820_series all-in-one
device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60000' is a ESCL DeskJet 5820 series [BR816FF15F06BN] flatbed scanner


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI                                         Model                                     
  -------------------------------------------------  ------------------------------------------
  hp:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=BR816FF15F06BN  HP DeskJet 5820 series                    

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------


DeskJet_5820
------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=BR816FF15F06BN
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet_5820.ppd
PPD Description: HP Deskjet 5820 Series, hpcups 3.20.3
Printer status: impressora DeskJet_5820 está inativa; habilitada desde dom 07 jun 2020 00:16:13
error: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=BR816FF15F06BN
error: Device not found
error: Communication status: Failed


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             DeskJet_5820                   Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/052' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'

-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
None

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
None


Total Errors: 1
Total Warnings: 0


Done.
```

Comment: Your device need HPLIP [>=3.16.3](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Deb-packages `hplip-gui` should work out-the-box with it. Which errors did you get with it? Which version of HPLIP are you using now - deb or binary?

Comment: From where have you got `/etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet_5820.ppd` file ?

Comment: @N0rbert, the hplip version is 3.20.5, downloaded from HP's own website. During installation, the hplip-gui package was automatically installed. The errors were the ones I described above, stating that I couldn't find the ppd file, from my printer version. Thing I fixed by activating the CUPS program process. Finally, I think there is no difference between the version of the official repo and the one made available on the HP website, other than the newer version.

Comment: As for the referred file, the hplip itself installs a library with all the drivers of its machines in the system. I just redirected to get the generic version for my printer, being the 5820_series.